# Show that $u\in \mathcal C^{1,5/7}$ but not $\mathcal C^2$ where $u=\frac{7}{12}|x|^{12/7}$.

Tags: real-analysis

I recall that $[\cdot ]_{\mathcal C^{0,\alpha }([-1,1])}$ is given by $$[u]_{\mathcal C^{0,\alpha }}=\sup_{\substack{x,y\in[-1,1]\\ x\neq y }}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha },$$
and that $u\in \mathcal C^{1,\alpha }([-1,1])$ if $[u]_{C^{0,\alpha }}<\infty $ and $[u']_{\mathcal C^{0,\alpha }}<\infty $.

Let $$u(x)=\frac{7}{12}|x|^{\frac{12}{7}},\quad x\in [-1,1].$$

How can I show that $u\in \mathcal C^{1,\frac{5}{7}}([-1,1])$ but $u\notin \mathcal C^2([-1,1])$ ?

**Attempts**

$$u'(x)=|x|^{-2/7}x,\quad x\neq 0$$
and since it can be prolonged continuity at $0$. Therefore $u\in \mathcal C^1([-1,1])$. Now, I observe that $$(u'(x))^7=x^5\implies u'(x)=x^{\frac{5}{7}},$$

**Q1) Is such an implication correct ?**

**Q2) I tried to prove that for $\alpha \in ]0,1]$, the function $x\longmapsto x^\alpha$ belong to $\mathcal C^{0,\alpha }$, but didn't work. Is such a result correct ?**

I tried to upper bound $$\frac{|x^\alpha -y^\alpha |}{|x-y|^\alpha },$$
but with no success.

**Q3) How can I prove it's not $\mathcal C^2([-1,1])$ ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have that $u'(0)=0$ since 
$$\frac{u(x)-u(0)}{x-0}=\frac7{12}\frac{|x|^{12/7}}{x}\to 0$$ as $x\to 0$. To prove that $u$ is not $C^2$ prove that $u^\prime$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ by computing the limit
$$\frac{u^\prime(x)-u^\prime(0)}{x-0}=\frac{|x|^{-2/7}x-0}{x}.$$
For Q1, no, you need to keep the absolute value. Only when $x>0$ you have what you wrote.
For Q2, $(a+b)^\alpha\le a^\alpha+b^\alpha$ when $0<\alpha<1$ since the function is concave (see here [concave is subadditive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function) for a proof).

Comment: You meant $u'$ is not differentiable at $0.$ And you have the inequality backwards.

Comment: you are right. Thanks